# Facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

So this is a super..super super general question so forgive my ignorance. But regarding the facebook open graph using custom stories on web, Does the person have to click a specific button to publish a certain story or just visit a specific page (after already connecting to the app) ?

Comment: Sharing anything should always be triggered actively and explicitly by the user wherever possible. “Automatic” posts are not a good idea in general. And a story getting posted just because the user visited a certain page without the user expecting this to happen would definitively violate Platform Polices.

Comment: the user has to give you permission to post on their behalf to publish a story.

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean that you should post stories at any time without the user expecting this to happen. (Facebook had this for a while, that news sites etc. were allowed to publish a story along the lines of _“foo is reading article bar on example.com”_ automatically – but they abolished that again, and it is now explicitly against policy to do stuff like that.)

Comment: Are you sure? I'm just asking because i've never seen soundcloud or spotify & game apps ask again before the "this person is listening to this sound / song" story is published? Aside from initially asking for permission to do so in the first place. Wouldn't it defeat the point of getting permission if the person gives you permission to publish what they're doing on your page and you ask them repeatedly? At that point they might as well just share it manually.

Comment: There are certain exceptions, when users explicitly opt-in to have actions they take within an app (like listening to a song) being posted automatically. I suggest you go and read [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy), there’s a lot of examples in there about what is allowed and what not when you click on the question marks. For example 12.1e might be applicable for what you have in mind. And always remember: _“But others are doing it”_ has never been any kind of justification.

Comment: Yes that's what i am asking about. When a user opts in to have their actions published from within an app, does it happen from them clicking a specific button or being on a certain page. If i'm listening to Aerosmith on Soundcloud, was it was me pressing play or me being on the page longer than 10 seconds that triggered the story? I saw a video by the FB Developers where they clicked a button which triggered the autopost from the app but it was a test and i know every app doesn't operate like that. That's where the confusion came from. Thanks though.